# How to get custom fields values from WooCommerce orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I have checked similar questions but couldn't resolve the problem.

This is my code so far:

```
// Add VAT and SSN fields in billing address display
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address', 'custom_add_vergi_dairesi_vergi_no_formatted_billing_address', 10, 2 );
function custom_add_vergi_dairesi_vergi_no_formatted_billing_address( $fields, $order ) {
    $fields['vergi_dairesi'] = $order->billing_vergi_dairesi;
    $fields['vergi_no'] = $order->billing_vergi_no;

    return $fields;
}
```

It is giving me this error: *"billing_vergi_dairesi was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly"*.

So I replaced `$order->billing_vergi_dairesi;` and `$order->billing_vergi_no;` with `$order->get_billing_vergi_dairesi();` and `$order->get_billing_vergi_no();` Then I got: *"uncaught Error: Call to undefined method"*.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since WooCommerce 3, you need to use the `WC_Data` method `get_meta()` with the correct meta key(s) to get custom fields values from the WC_Order Object like:

```php
// Add VAT and SSN fields in billing address display
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address', 'custom_add_vergi_dairesi_vergi_no_formatted_billing_address', 10, 2 );
function custom_add_vergi_dairesi_vergi_no_formatted_billing_address( $fields, $order ) {
    $fields['vergi_dairesi'] = $order->get_meta('billing_vergi_dairesi');
    $fields['vergi_no']      = $order->get_meta('billing_vergi_no');

    return $fields;
}
```

Or may be starting with an underscore instead like:

```php
// Add VAT and SSN fields in billing address display
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address', 'custom_add_vergi_dairesi_vergi_no_formatted_billing_address', 10, 2 );
function custom_add_vergi_dairesi_vergi_no_formatted_billing_address( $fields, $order ) {
    $fields['vergi_dairesi'] = $order->get_meta('_billing_vergi_dairesi');
    $fields['vergi_no']      = $order->get_meta('_billing_vergi_no');

    return $fields;
}
```

It should works.

> Check in `wp_postmeta` table that `billing_vergi_dairesi` and `billing_vergi_no` are the correct meta keys.

See: [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)